# Space around the checkbox

Tags: asp.net, html, css

i am confused.

using following code:

```
<div>
   <table class="filter_component_css">
      <tr>
         <td>purchase order</td>
         <td><asp:TextBox CssClass="search_format" ID="po_textbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>material desc</td>
         <td><asp:TextBox CssClass="search_format" ID="material_desc_textbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>supplier</td>
          <td><asp:TextBox CssClass="search_format" ID="supplier_textbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>manufacturer</td>
          <td><asp:TextBox CssClass="search_format" ID="manufacturer_textbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
      </tr>

       <tr>
          <td>special tools</td>              
          <td><asp:Checkbox CssClass="checkbox_format" ID="tools_checkbox" runat="server"/></td>
      </tr>


      <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <asp:Button ID="buttonReset" runat="server" Text="Reset" OnClick="submitResetClick"/>
                <asp:Button ID="buttonSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="submitSearchClick"/>
            </td>
      </tr>

    </table>
</div>
```

and CSS class:

```
.checkbox_format
{
        border: 1px solid black;    
}
```

In the result, I see spaces around the checkbox.
I am testing app in IE7.
My question - Is it possible to remove the spaces around the checkbox?

Answer (score 2):

try this css. hope this will help.

```
.checkbox_format
{
        margin:0 !important;
        display: block;
        border: 1px solid black;    
}
```

Comment: It works fine when i tried it out? Or perhaps you can try removing the padding and margin from the `<td>` element as well?

Answer (score 0):

try tu put that in one line, like:

```
<tr><td colspan="2"><asp:Button ID="buttonReset" runat="server" Text="Reset" OnClick="submitResetClick"/><asp:Button ID="buttonSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="submitSearchClick"/></td></tr>
```

if Im not bad, that solves that issue

Comment: I don't understand how putting in one line can solve the problem. Are you joking?

Comment: have you tried? because I am not joking, that could solve that issue

Comment: I solve a similar issue time ago doing it, I dont know either how the browser behaves, specially how IE browser behaves, but if works is good for me

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes are notoriously difficult to style. Browsers tend to have different ideas about how much space should be around each checkbox.

Your best bet is to add a rule removing margin and paddings from the checkbox.

```
.checkbox_format
{
    border: 1px solid black;    
    margin:0; padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more than a year old but I had the same problem and was trying to solve it. The problem is that the asp.net checkbox is enclosed in a span when it is implemented in the html which does not propagates the styles properly. My solution is to use:

```
.checkbox_format input
{
    border: 1px solid black;    
    margin:0; padding:0;
}
```

Hope it helps someone else!